# Add string to bottom of file if file doesn't already exist

Tags: bash, grep

I have the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=sidekiq.yml
DIR=/home/<user>/*/current/config
DISCOVERY=$(find $DIR -name "$FILE"|cut -d/ -f4)

for i in $DISCOVERY

do grep -qF '^command[sidekiq_$i]' /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/config/sidekiq.conf || echo command[sidekiq_$i]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -c 1:1 -a "'$i ['" | sudo tee -a /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/config/sidekiq.conf

done
```

The purpose of the script is to add a line to a config file if a matching line doesn't already exist.

When I run the script for a second time it still adds the string in.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest issue is that you are single-quoting the parameter to grep:

> grep -qF '^command[sidekiq_$i]' /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/config/sidekiq.conf

which prevents variable expansion for `$i`. You need to use double-quotes if you want `$i` to be expanded. The next issue is that grep's `-F` flag forces grep to see the search-string as a *fixed* pattern, not as a regular expression, so the caret becomes a caret instead of an anchor.

If you need the anchor, then drop the `-F` and escape the square brackets:

```
grep -q "^command\[sidekiq_$i\]" /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/config/sidekiq.conf
```

or if you don't need the caret anchor, then keep `-F` and drop the caret:

```
grep -qF "command[sidekiq_$i]" /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/config/sidekiq.conf
```

Comment: Great thanks...changed it to 
grep -qF "command[sidekiq_$i]" /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/config/sidekiq.conf